# How to show row index in grid js using react js

Tags: reactjs, gridjs

currently creating my datatable using grid.js in reactjs.

**This is my code**

```
<Grid
    data={data.filter(e => e.status != 0)}
    columns={[
        {
            id: 'url',
            name: 'url',
            hidden: true

        }, {
            id: 'id',
            name: '#',
            formatter: (cell) => _(this.showIndexNo()) //<-- where i do the function to display row index number

        }, {
            id: 'name',
            name: 'Name'
        }, {
            id: 'smgk_name',
            name: 'SM Name',
            formatter: (cell, row) => _(this.showSmlink(row.cells[0].data, row.cells[3].data))

        }, {
            id: 'email',
            name: 'Email',
            // formatter: (cell) => _(moment(cell).format(MOMENT_FORMAT))

        },
        {
            id: 'id',
            name: 'Actions',
            formatter: (cell) => _(this.showButton(cell))
            //(cell) => `Name: ${cell}`
        }
    ]}

    search={true}
    sort={true}
/>
```

I want to display the row index/ auto increment in my grid js.
How should i edit this code?

```
 showIndexNo() {

 const { subscriberData } = this.state;

 let a = [];

 return (subscriberData.filter(e => e.status != 0).map((item, i) => i ) ) }
```

and I get this result:

[image]

I cannot use ID as the row Index as when I delete one details the Id will still be there only status will changed to deleted(this wont be displayed in grid), so I need row Index. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
return (subscriberData.filter(e => e.status != 0).map((item, i) =>
  return { ...item,
    rowIndex: i //use rowIndex as column
  }))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, mapping is not working in this case... i just want to know how to access rowIndex

Comment: Hi, i put the mapping at wrong place . It is working... thank you :) and sorry hehe